# how to connect mysql installed on google cloud

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform

Currently installed mysql-server on google cloud

I changed `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` with `bind-address = 0.0.0.0`

I created a mysql account with `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO user@'%'`

I also restart mysql service

I double checked 3306 port

however, when I connect this mysql server `mysql -h 'google cloud ip' -P 3306 -u user -p`, I always got 'ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on google cloud ip'

Comment: Can you successfully ping the ip-address?

Comment: yes, I could ping the ip-address

Comment: Take a look at https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mysql-remote-access

Comment: I am guessing that the firewall is refusing your connection.

Comment: @Noob how to change the google cloud firewall...?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for @Noob answer, yes, it is about google cloud firewall filter